# Finding the angular velocity of a satellite revolving around the a revolving secondary body

Tags: newtonian-gravity, coriolis-effect

I recently came across the concept of the hill sphere radius,where we find the maximum distance from the secondary body where a satellite can stay stationary with respect to the secondary body, without falling into the primary body. I tried solving for the case where the satellite was also revolving around the secondary body taking only the position of the satellite along the line joining the the primary and secondary bodies to simplify calculations.

I solved using a rotating frame centered at the primary (assuming its mass much greater than the secondary), rotating with the angular velocity $\Omega$ of revolution of the secondary body such that in this frame there would only be the revolution of the satellite ($\omega$) around the secondary. I arbitrarily chose the direction of $\Omega$ and $\omega$ such that both the satellite and secondary revolve around the primary body anticlockwise and the satellite revolves around the secondary body clockwise. I'm not sure if this has any effect on anything other than the direction of the coriolis force.

Balancing forces we get,

$$ \frac {GM_Sm}{(R-r)^2} + m\omega^2r = 2m \Omega × v_{rot} + m\Omega^2(R-r) +\frac {GMm}{r^2}$$

m: mass of satellite     R: distance between the primary and secondary bodies

M: Mass of secondary     r: distance between the satellite and secondary body

$M_s$: Mass of primary

since r<<R, using binomial approximation on $ \frac {GM_Sm}{(R-r)^2} $ and cancelling m throughout,

$$ \frac {GM_S}{R^2}(1+2\frac rR) + \omega^2r = 2 \Omega × v_{rot} + \Omega^2(R-r) +\frac {GM}{r^2}$$

since $\Omega^2 = \frac {GM_S}{R^3}$ and $v_{rot} = \omega r$, we can simplify this to a quadratic in $\omega$:

$$ \omega^2 - 2\Omega \omega + (3\Omega^2 - \frac {GM}{r^3}) = 0$$

which has roots,

$$ \omega = \Omega \pm \sqrt {\frac {GM}{r^3} - 2\Omega^2} $$

Im not completely sure of my working as i havent learnt about coriolis forces in much depth and if my assumptions are valid. My main questions are :

1. Does my working seem correct?
2. What does the existence of 2 roots imply
3. As opposed to the usual example of a ball appearing to move away when thrown from a merry go round, Im not able to understand intuitively the direction of the coriolis force here (radially inwards to the secondary body).

Comment: Why is $r\ll R$? If the satellite is orbiting the primary, wouldn't $r\approx R$? (e.g., the distance from our own satellites to the moon is basically the same as the distance of earth to the moon). Or am I misreading your description of the locations of things?

Comment: R is the distance between the primary and secondary bodies and r is the distance between the satellite and the secondary, for example R being distance between the Sun and Earth and r being the distance between earth and moon.

Comment: Okay, so the satellite is orbiting the secondary, not the primary.